# oracle listener reply and answer on same port

Tags: listener, port, oracle12c

Normal when a client starts a session with a server. It starts on one port and then the remaining conversation takes place on port assigned it by the server

I don't want to open that big of a port range on my firewall. So is there a way to configure the oracle listener to answer and continue the same port that it started on?

Comment: Why do you think you need to open a big port range - are you talking about the client end or the server end?

Comment: I changed the listener to port 21 and opened traffic. TNSping resolves the address before saying the operation times out. Locally on this network, I can connect without any issues. It when I try to come in from the out side that I have the problem. I have other services running on port 22 and 8080 and those work just fine, so I know its not my router/firewall.

Comment: 21 is an odd choice as it's usually used (reserved?) for FTP. Are you sure the listener is running on that port successfully, not ftpd? Is port 21 open on your firewall?

Comment: Yes. port 21 is open and I tested the listener as well. I'm purposely using 21 because is a common port that most other (corporate and what not) firewalls will allow, where as 1521 might be blocked.

Comment: In my experience 21 is often blocked because FTP is considered insecure. It certainly seems to be being blocked in your network. <shrug> Anyway, the problem is with that port number, not with other ports in some other range being opened.

Comment: I also tried port 443 and had the same issue. So I'm more inclined to believe the problem is in the port conversation not the port itself.

Comment: It sounds like your firewall is a whitelist and you only have ports 22 and 8080 open. So, if you use 1521 like normal and then ask for that to be whitelisted you're in the same position. I can absolutely guarantee you that corporate firewalls do not allow servers to connect to port 21 of your database - nothing will be able to connect to your box without an explicit request and playing around with the ports will just get you a few funny looks.

Comment: USE_SHARED_SOCKET= TRUE under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME...Would this force the oracle server to do everything on port 1521?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your firewall supports sql net proxy, you only need to open port 1521.